# While loop for checking grades is invalid is not working for some reason

Tags: c++, arrays, function, while-loop

So here is the question that I am working on

Grades with input validation (C++). Modify grade programs with arrays and functions. (the program should minimally have functions for average, min, max, # above average, etc. total of 4 functions) Add logic (to the main) so that if the user enters an invalid grade (lower than zero, higher than 100), the user will be issued an error message and then be allowed to reenter the grade. This will repeat as long as the user enters invalid grades. You will need a While loop.

When I enter a number lower than 0, it is not executing the code in the while loop for some reason, Also my minimum function is not working either

Here's the code that I have for the main function and the minimum function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double average(double x[], int n);
double maximum(double x[], int n);
double minimum(double x[], int n); 
int nAboveAvg(double x[], int n);



int main()
{
   double grades[50];
   int ngrades;

   cout<<"How many grades? (max = 50) ";
   cin>>ngrades;

   //create for loop to get grades from user
   for(int i = 0; i<ngrades; i++)
   {
          cout<<"Enter grade ";
      cin>> grades[i];
      while(grades[i]< 0 || grades[i] > 100)
      {
          cout<<"Invalid grade- please enter again"<<endl;
          cin>>grades[i];
      }
  }

  //call the functions
  double avg = average(grades, ngrades);
  double max = maximum(grades, ngrades);
  double min = minimum(grades, ngrades);
  int nAbove = nAboveAvg(grades, ngrades);
  //display results

  cout << "Average = " << avg << endl;
  cout << "# above average = " << nAbove << endl;
  cout<<"Max value is = "<<max<<endl;
  cout<<"Min value is = "<<min<<endl;


}
//Minimum function

double minimum(double x[], int npts)
{

  double min = x[0];

  for(int i = 0; i < npts; i++) 
  {
        if(x[i] < min) 
        {

            min = x[i];
        }
    }
  return min;
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine. Whats your problem?

Comment: "less than 0" - how is your actual input look like?

Comment: Your minimum function is fine.Make sure you are entering the value less then 0 for `grades[i]` not for  `ngrades` :p ..just wanted to make sure..

Answer (score -2):

Your code seems to work for me.
Did you try to rebuild it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8XiX.png

Comment: Hmm that is weird I complied also but it still doesn't work for me

Comment: How many grades? (max = 50) 3
Enter grade -1
Enter grade 2
Enter grade 4
Average = 1.66667
# above average = 2
Max value is = 4

--------------------------------
Process exited after 7.955 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: How many grades? (max = 50) 3
Enter grade -1
Enter grade 2
Enter grade 4
Average = 1.66667
# above average = 2
Max value is = 4

--------------------------------
Process exited after 7.955 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: this is how my output looks like

Comment: Ok nevermind I got it too work but its not printing the minimum value

Comment: I mean i commented out calling not implemented max, avg and nAbove functions to make this screen.